# Can I add anuglar app to my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, angular, github, github-pages

So i have built an angular website that uses the GoogleBooksAPI to fetch some book list. And then I show it on my single page app.

Now, i'd like to deploy it somehow to see if it's working.
So i tried to add the project to github pages. github project link:

https://github.com/DrorSC/DrorSC.github.io

And was unsuccesful..
So i thought on a different option. I have a domain, and a wordpress site on it. Maybe i can add the files to my Cpanel and load it into my domain? Or can i do it straight from wordpress?
Tried to look for answers, couldn't find.
Please help. thank you :)

Comment: As you have a Angular application that uses angular cli, Run ng build to build the project. The build artifacts will be stored in the dist/ directory. Use the --prod flag for a production build. Then copy the content from the dist/ folder to your webserver of choice. As it is a regular html/javascript application it could be hosten on any webserver available. For example your domain with the cpanel website theat you describe.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I think Angular Element will be your best choice. It works the best if you want to integrate Angular web app into your existing website.

[Building Custom Elements / Web Components with Angular 6](https://medium.com/@tomsu/building-web-components-with-angular-elements-746cd2a38d5b)

Answer (score -1):

After build the project. You can use the content of the `dist` directory into your host.

If you will put your code into a subfolder, you will need specify the path as argument on the CLI for the build.

Comment: Yes, I know i can take the dist folder after "ng build --prod" and use it where index.html is the page that will be shown.
My question is - Is there a way to integrate That folder for example into a Page in Wordpress?

Comment: I understand. I think it's not a problem to load the application inside a specific page. I didn't experienced it before. Maybe you need don't load the head/footer tags to avoid js conflicts. VueJS seams proper for work with components inside pages.